# Using line integrals to find area

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

I am trying to find the area of a wall.
I have been given that the base is part of the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin, lying in the first quadrant.
I am also given that the height is equal to $$f(x, y) = y + 4x$$
How would I go about solving this? 
I know that I have $$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$ and that I want dA using line integrals, but beyond this I'm a bit unsure as to what approach I should use.
Do I want to find $$\int \int y + 4x dx dy$$ with limits $$x = \pm \sqrt(1-y^2)$$ and $$y = \pm 1$$ or am I thinking about this in the wrong way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I want dA using line integrals" Integrals with $\mathrm dA$ are generally not line integrals. And line integrals generally don't have $\mathrm dA$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The base is part of the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin, lying in the first quadrant" is parameterized as follow

$ \gamma :[0,\pi/2] \to \mathbb{R}^2 , \gamma(t) = (cos(t),sin(t))$

The height is equal to

$  f(x,y) = y+4x $

Then

$\int_{C} f \cdot \ d \gamma  = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} f(\gamma(t))||\gamma'(t)|| \,dt$